# working with the google OAuth 2.0 in android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, token, google-sheets-api

I have a android app that requires permission from the user to access its google spreadsheets (the scope is google spreadsheet API).

At the first time the app is launched its all good, I can acces the spreadsheets just fine. **I am saving the email address the user chooses to the Shared Preferences.**

What I want is that in the next time that the user launches the app (after the first time), the app will only get the token (because I already have the email address of the user) without the user having to go through the account picker again.

I imagine this has been done before, because the user should only choose his account once. none the less, I couldn't figure what is the best practice for it.

**He is the Google OAuth 2.0 class**

straight from here http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html

```
public class GoogleAccountActivity extends Activity {

    static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT = 1000;
    static final int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR = 1001;
    static final int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_AUTH_ERROR = 1002;

    String mEmail; 
    private static final String SCOPE =
            "oauth2:https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/";
    private Intent homeIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        homeIntent=new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class); 
         // next activity tto launch
        pickUserAccount();
    }


    private void getUsername() {
        if (mEmail == null) {
            pickUserAccount();
        } else {
            if (isDeviceOnline()) {
                new GetUsernameTask(this, mEmail, SCOPE).execute();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_online, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isDeviceOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {
            // Receiving a result from the AccountPicker
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mEmail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                // With the account name acquired, go get the auth token
                getUsername();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The account picker dialog closed without selecting an account.
                // Notify users that they must pick an account to proceed.
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.pick_account, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_AUTH_ERROR ||
                requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR)
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Receiving a result that follows a GoogleAuthException, try auth again
            getUsername();
        }
    }

    private void pickUserAccount() {
        String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"};
        Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
    }



    public void handleException(final Exception e) {
        // Because this call comes from the AsyncTask, we must ensure that the following
        // code instead executes on the UI thread.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (e instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException) {
                    // The Google Play services APK is old, disabled, or not present.
                    // Show a dialog created by Google Play services that allows
                    // the user to update the APK
                    int statusCode = ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException)e)
                            .getConnectionStatusCode();
                    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(statusCode,
                            GoogleAccountActivity.this,
                            REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
                    dialog.show();
                } else if (e instanceof UserRecoverableAuthException) {
                    // Unable to authenticate, such as when the user has not yet granted
                    // the app access to the account, but the user can fix this.
                    // Forward the user to an activity in Google Play services.
                    Intent intent = ((UserRecoverableAuthException)e).getIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(intent,
                            REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class GetUsernameTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
        Activity mActivity;
        String mScope;
        String mEmail;

        GetUsernameTask(Activity activity, String name, String scope) {
            this.mActivity = activity;
            this.mScope = scope;
            this.mEmail = name;
        }

        /**
         * Executes the asynchronous job. This runs when you call execute()
         * on the AsyncTask instance.
         */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                String token = fetchToken();
                if (token != null) {
                    homeIntent.putExtra("userToken", token);
                    startActivity(homeIntent); // starting the Home Activity
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // The fetchToken() method handles Google-specific exceptions,
                // so this indicates something went wrong at a higher level.
                // TIP: Check for network connectivity before starting the AsyncTask.
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Gets an authentication token from Google and handles any
         * GoogleAuthException that may occur.
         */
        protected String fetchToken() throws IOException {
            try {
                return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
                // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present
                // so we need to show the user some UI in the activity to recover.
                handleException(userRecoverableException);
            } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
                // Some other type of unrecoverable exception has occurred.
                // Report and log the error as appropriate for your app.
            }
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

It works fine for the first launch, but I am not sure what to do in the next time.

***To sum up:***

1. I want to understand if I need to get a token every time I launch the app??
2. and if so, How do I do only the fetching of the token (and handling exceptions) without the account picking and the other stuff required in the first launch.
3. Do I need to work with a refresh token? because I read about it but didn't see any example for it in the do.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Ofek

Answer (score 0):

In Case of android phone or any device which has google+,
You can just check for google+ login.

If you are using any other device or android device without gmail,
First time you need to fetch a token from google.
Later on you need to refresh your token as it might expire.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices

Comment: thanks for your answer! a few questions: with the google+ sign in button, does the user only have to sign in once? after the first time he launches the app and signs in, is it always going to be signed in? and if so, how should I get the access token in the not-google-auth activity (lets say, my HomeActivity)? because on the first launch the user will sign in and get a token, but in the next times, I want to direct the user to another activity (to my homeActivity right wawy, without havig to see the google activity again), so I want to know how can I get the token in another activity? thanks

Comment: You have to login through google + just to get information from google profile. You need to send the token to your server and then check validation there. Later you send your own token to your client and google will not involve in it.
google's token has some expiry time.

Comment: You can also get refresh token from google to your server and save it in your app and access it through your server for further login.

Comment: I don't want to get information from the google profile. All I want to do is to access and write to the spreadsheets. in the first launch it working fine (see code above), the account picker shows a list of accounts, the user chooses one and access token is received. the thing is that, in the next time the user will launch the app, I want just to get a token for him without him having to go through the account picker (because I already have the email address). so my question basically is how to get the token alone? (from another activity). thanks

Comment: and just to clarify, I don't have a server side, I just want to access the spreadsheets from the app on the phone.

Comment: Access tokens normally last 1 Hour. You use the refresh token to get a new access token. To get a new access token, check the code you are using, as it probably includes a method to get a new access token with the refresh token. Also store the refresh token on the Phone, in the app.
Regards the link above, it has a section "Using a refresh token" that shows the raw message used to get a new access token.